# How to curl to paypal in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, curl, paypal

I'm trying to post to PayPal's API with cURL in Nodejs using Request but get nothing in return:

```
var consentJSONData = 'AuthorizationCodeForNoNetworkEnvironment';

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
    qs: 'grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=token&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&code=' + consentJSONData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type:': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' : 'Basic Y2xpZW50X2lkOnNlY3JldA=='
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    console.log(error); <- null
    console.log(response); <- a whole bunch of stuff, but don't see the json that I'm looking for.
    console.log(body); <- emtpy
}

request(options, callback);
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I even close?

I'm using my sandbox and when authorizing a user for a future payment I get this credential key back: AuthorizationCodeForNoNetworkEnvironment

Also, PayPal says to send 'client_id:secret' but I encoded that with base64 because I didn't know how to send the parameter.  Maybe that has something to do with it.

Here are PayPal's docs: [PayPal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md)

Here are Request's docs: [Request](https://github.com/request/request)

console.log(error): null

---

Turns out I know nothing about OAuth2 and was literally Base64'ing 'client_id:secret' rather than my client_id and secret provided by PayPal.

Comment: What's the response status code?

Comment: please put a console.log(error) in the callback and tell us what you see.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal's Node.js SDK turned out to be the best solution: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK